# Highcharts Stacked Area: legend hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, highcharts

I am working on a chart that has a very large number of series in a stacked area.

It looks like there is some sort of event being fired whenever the mouse hovers over a series in the legend.  The default seems to be to make the line at the top of the stacked area a bit thicker.  Unfortunately, this is very hard to interpret in the plot I am working on.  It would be much more beneficial if the color of the area changed- even just going from translucent to fully opaque.

Is this possible? If so, How?

Answer (score 0):

You can define color like this

```
states: {
  hover: {
    color: 'rgba(68, 188, 93, 1)'
  }
}
```

in each series.

Example (Bar Chart) - http://jsfiddle.net/tosx33ae/1/

Comment: Almost what I am looking for, however I would like the opacity to change when hovering over the legend, rather than the actual area.